# AWS Beanstalk CLI keeps deploying react/npm development build

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, npm, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a react app and two AWS Beanstalk instances: development and production. I am trying to deploy a development build of said React app to the development environment and a production build to the production environment.

Each environment is set up with a different environment variable (URL of the API that should be called), so the output should be different.
Both API URLs work when called directly through the browser, so I know it's not an issue with them.

I thought the process of deploying in development went like this:
For dev: `npm start build` > `eb deploy -e development`
For prod: `npm run build` > `eb deploy -e production`

When opening the development web page, everything works as expected: The development env variable is being called and some output is generated.

However, when opening the production web page, I get an error message (because of a missing environment variable):

`This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.`

But I thought my app just did crash in production? This clearly shows me that I did not correctly deploy the production build.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Hi, did you try to check which environment is currently active? 
eb list shows you a list of environments and has an asterix (*) beside the active one.
You can then eb use [environment_name] to select it and then eb deploy.
Or alternatively you can use eb deploy -e [environment_name]

Comment: Hi @RohitNethi this is actually what I did. I am deploying into the right environment, the problem is that the wrong build is being deployed aparently. I adjusted my question to reflect this problem better.

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of experimentation, it turns out that Beanstalk runs the command `npm start` per default when the node.js app is being restarted or a new version is being deployed.
Changing this behaviour is possible (*Configuration > Software > Modify > node command*).

A temporary solution (certainly not the perfect solution) was to:

- setting the node command to `node server.js`
- install the [node.js express framework](https://expressjs.com/)
- include a file `server.js` in the root directory

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(8081);
```

- build the file locally via `npm run build`
- remove `build/` from `.gitignore`, so that it is being included in the local repo
- `git commit -a` (Do **not** `git push` unless you have reason to do so)
- deploy the app again via `eb deploy`